# Getting an error while running the docker-compose command - "a Windows version 10.0.20348-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.19044 host"

Tags: docker

I am trying to install `Sitecore 10.3 with Docker`. While running *docker-compose* command I have encountered below issue.

The error message I get is:

> a Windows version 10.0.20348-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.19044 host

[image: Getting an error while running the docker-compose command - "a Windows version 10.0.20348-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.19044 host"]

Has anyone faced this?

Comment: Add error text for SEO reasons.

Comment: It's because of the difference in the versions of Windows.

Comment: @SumitHelaiya, here is the error text. 
a Windows version 10.0.20348-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.19044 host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the differences in the Windows version.
For that, we need to update the below parameters in the `.env` file,

```
SITECORE_VERSION=10.3-ltsc2019 -- line no 3 
EXTERNAL_IMAGE_TAG_SUFFIX=ltsc2019 -- line no 36
```

And re-run the docker-compose command.

Check out the below links for checking the compatible version for your Windows machine.
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is running on an old Windows 10 version, and auto updates disabled, Your organization has turned off automatic updates. Try the `ltsc2019` version which uses older windows OR update your machine to the compatible version in this case (`10.0.20348`    **Windows Server 2022 Version 21H2**)

Also, it is always good to check the Prerequisites before proceeding with any Sitecore setup.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/developer-tools/set-up-the-environment.html

Hope it helps!